# No see new data right after insert to MariaDB(MYSQL) on Linux server only

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel

I have page to insert/update invoice  writing by LARAVEL & MariaDB

Right after insert an item to invoice I call Load Invoice Detail function.
The debug show that the dataset return does not contain the new item I've just inserted.

But I copy the select query to select all items from this invoice in Load Invoice Detail function and paste it to PHPMYADMIN and run. I can see new item I 've just inserted.

This case does not happen when I run web app and database serve on my computer, It just happened when I push Web App and Database on Linux serve.

Is there any config task on database on Linux to fix this problem?
Help me please.
Thank you very much indeed

Comment: Are you using auto-generated id and requerying? Are you refreshing your view? Are you using asynchronous or synchronous save method?

Comment: Hi Ezani,
As your instruct, I call refresh the page, It works. Thank so much

Comment: Hi Dang, glad I could help you. I have converted my comments to an Answer. Hope you could tick it as your accepted answer. If you have any other questions feel free to ask me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the page to ensure the data is reloaded.